# Set an element from droplist when the page has been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to set an element from droplist when the page has been loaded.
My code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!");
    changeStatus();
});

function changeStatus() {
    console.log("chStatus!");
    $('#status_change option:last').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
</script>

<select id="status_change">
    <option value="noselected">...</option>
    <option value="new">Processing</option>
    <option value="todrop">To drop</option>
    <option value="onbuyer">On buyer</option>
    <option value="resent">Resent</option>
</select>
```

The last option doesn't select, when the page has been loaded? Where is my error?

Comment: Try `$('#status_change').val($('#status_change option:last').val());`

Comment: It works fine [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3xhb9nw/)

Comment: @AlexChar not on my browser (Safari 9). I guess it may be a case of browsers' different behaviours.

Comment: @Tushar's solution works though (http://jsfiddle.net/s3xhb9nw/1/). I think you can propose it as an answer.

Comment: Yes but it is probably not cross-browser (whosever the fault is). It doesn't work on my browser. And I guess not on OP's one either or he wouldn't have asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, you should add the attribute to the element itself instead of adding it on page load.

```
<option value="resent" selected="selected">Resent</option>
```

---

`$('#status_change option:last').attr('selected', 'selected');` should work. However, due to browser inconsistencies pointed out by @[Quentin Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2212031/quentin-roy), it is not working on Safari 9.

As an option you can also try `prop`

```
$('#status_change option:last').prop('selected', true);
```

You can set the value of the last `option` from `select`.

```
$('#status_change').val($('#status_change option:last').val());
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/z3xgokce/1/)